# How to prove the form of the functions which are symmetric with respect set?

Tags: convex-analysis, orthogonality, symmetric-functions

> Let $G$ be any set of orthogonal linear transformations of $R^{n}$ onto itself. A function $f$ is said to be symmetric with respect to $G$ if
> $$
> f(A x)=f(x), \quad \forall x, \quad \forall A \in G .
> $$
> The functions on $R^{n}$ which are symmetric with respect to the set of all orthogonal transformations of $R^{n}$ are, of course, those of the form
> $$
> f(x)=g(|x|),
> $$
> where $|\cdot|$ is the Euclidean norm and $g$ is a function on $[0,+\infty)$.

The above discussion is in Convex Analysis, but I don't quite understand the following:

1. How the function $g$ is constructed?
2. Why $f$ has such a form?

Comment: $G$ is not a function but a set. Are you asking how the function $g$ is constructed? $g(x) = f(x,0,0,\dots,0)$ for $x\ge0$, for example.

Comment: @GregMartin Yes, i ask how the function  is constructed(I will modify the description of the problem).

Comment: @GregMartin I'm so sorry, I didn't understand what you meant. I don't think the function $g$ you have constructed satisfies the above requirements. For example, the function should satisfies $f([1,0,...,0])=g(1)=f([0,1,0,...0])$, but the g you have constructed do not satisfies.

Comment: For general $f$ it doesn't, but under the assumption on $f$ (that it is symmetric with respect to the set of all orthogonal transformations) it actually does!

Comment: @GregMartin Sorry,  but the above quote said: $f$ needs to satisfy $f(x)=g(|x|)$. Therefore, $g$ need satisfy  $f([1,0, \ldots, 0])=g(1)=f([0,1,0, \ldots, 0])$.

Comment: Yes, my comment stands. Try writing down an example of a function $f$ *that satisfies the assumption* and checking that $g(1)$ really does equal both values.

Comment: @GregMartin sorry, I do not understand, because  the function you given  $g$ is not satifies $f([1,0, \ldots, 0])=g(1)=f([0,1,0, \ldots, 0])$